# How to Store an Error Exception message

Tags: java

Let say in my Java Application, I have a `throws` Exception in my main class and I have a try and catch around my code. In my catch part, I have an code with will display an Exception in my application. What I want to know is, is there anyway I can store this exception message that displayed in the console and then send this exception message to my email address? I got the email connecting part working, all I need to do it find a way to store that error exception message. Help will be appreciated.

try and catch part

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{


    try {

      //method and code go here



    }
    catch (Exception e){
        //Exception
         throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI-U r handling exception using try catch block, so from main method no need throws Exception.

Comment: oh right, I forgot about that, thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call `getMessage()` on the exception object to get the message:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    String message = e.getMessage();
    // Do whatever with the message, for example e-mail it somewhere
}
```

If you want the complete stack trace of the exception, it's a little more work to get that into a string:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    pw.flush();
    String stackTrace = sw.toString();
    // do whatever you want to do with stackTrace
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I am looking for !

Comment: First option should really be `e.toString()` to get the exception name too. Message alone of often meaningless, e.g. this expression `(new int[0])[1]` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with message `1`.

Comment: Can't we use:
String stackTrace = e.getStackTrace().toString();
(I'M NOT SURE)

Comment: @Saud `getStackTrace()` returns an array, and `toString()` of an array does *not* print the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use to get the error message:

```
e.getMessage();
```

If you want to store the message, simply do:

```
String message = e.getMessage();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `toString()` method of exception class, like this:

```
String message = e.toString();
```

You'll get information about the class name, the locale message and the error message. Here is more detail information than `getMessage` method.

To store the exception message for further use you might create class field too.

Comment: You can also do ""+e as a shortcut

Comment: @shieldgenerator7, there is a bad way to `String` cast

Comment: Why? It gets around any possible NullPointerExceptions

Comment: @shieldgenerator7, if we are in the `catch` statement, we don't get `NPE`